# How to cast 1 and 0 to true and false in Ruby. Want a boolean or logical out

Tags: ruby

I need to index into a hash that I have defined in terms of "true" and "false"

```
colorHash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }
colorHash["answers"][true]  = "#00CC00"
colorHash["answers"][false] = "#FFFFFF"
```

For testing purposes, I am indexing with rand(2) and that fails.  If I index with **true** it works.

I was looking for something like

rand(2).logical

but find nothing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a simple (although not very exciting) way to do this:

```
rand(2) == 1
```

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this?

```
[true,false][rand(2)]
```

That is, return a random result from the true/false array.  It's certainly more verbose than `rand(2) == 1`, though.

Comment: I like this idea! In Ruby 1.9 you can do `[true,false].sample`

Answer (score 5):

I think this is one of the coolest ways, and #sample is one of the less known Array methods:

[true, false].sample

Edit: This is only valid in Ruby >= 1.9

Answer (score 1):

`[true,false].shuffle`
or `[true,false].sort { rand }`

```
def get_bool
   [true,false].shuffle.shift
end
```