# Rails Evaluate Integer as Boolean

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model which stores user settings as 0 or 1 (for true/false). In my code, I'm having to do this:

```
if @user.settings.show_menu == 1
  # do this
end
```

How can I leave out the `== 1` or `== 0`? I've tried:

```
if @user.settings.show_menu
  # do this
end
```

But it's not evaluating as true, same with when using `!@user.settings.show_menu`

It's been a long day, please guide me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: In Ruby, only `nil` and `false` are considered falsy. So the correct test really is to check `== 0` or `== 1`.

Comment: If your migration was defined to expect this as a boolean rather than int value, Rails should be handling this on its own.

Comment: And there's the problem, I didn't setup the column as boolean XD. Changing now, thanks for the tip

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast 1 and 0 to true and false in Ruby. Want a boolean or logical out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067522/how-to-cast-1-and-0-to-true-and-false-in-ruby-want-a-boolean-or-logical-out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails there is a `boolean` column for use with the database that stores as a number and converts accordingly. Generally this is encoded in the database as `SMALLINT`. If you have a regular `INT` you could always migrate to convert them.

An example migration:

```
change_table :table_name do |t|
   t.change(:boolean_column, :boolean)
end
```

Within your app, the standard practice is to refer to boolean flags with their `?` method version, like:

```
if (@user.settings.show_menu?)
  # ...
end
```

If this method is not defined, you'll get an exception which can lead you to discover the problem. This compares favorably to having it always evaluate as true.